# For given Key Value pair find and replace all keys with corresponding values at once in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Please let me know how do I achieve below output state in googlespreadsheet, for given key(Column3) and value(Column4) in below table. This is just a example I've file with huge records.

**Input State :**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
123              123    ABC
123              456    DEF
123              789    GHI
456         
456         
456         
789         
789
```

**Output State :**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
123     ABC     123     ABC
123     ABC     456     DEF
123     ABC     789     GHI
456     DEF     
456     DEF     
456     DEF     
789     GHI     
789     GHI
```

I've tried few hacks but didn't work. Dear excel experts please help here.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B2 put the following and fill down

```
=iferror(vlookup(A1,$C$1:$D$3,2,false),"")
```

[image]